# SharePoint 2010: Is FAST Search a separate install from Server and Foundation?

Tags: fast-search, search

IS SharePoint Search installed by default?
If so, how do I know if it is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes FAST Search is a separate install.

SharePoint Search is installed by default, to check look at the Service Applications in addition to the Services on your server.